# Set different font size of ticktext in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, font-size

I tried to put the font size of the first line of ticks (Tick 1, Tick 2, Tick 3) in size 15 and green and the second line of ticks in size 13 and red (description 1, description 2, description 3).

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np 


df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Canada'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Canada')
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis=dict(title="", showgrid=True,
           ticktext=[f"<b>Tick 1</b> <br> description 1", "<b>Tick 2</b> <br> description 2", "<b>Tick 3</b> <br> description 3"],
           tickvals=np.arange(72,78,2),
            tickfont = dict(size = 12))
)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Plotly's `annotation` feature, hide the original tick labels by setting the `showticklabels` attribute to `False` then we can add custom annotations for each tick with the desired font sizes and colors.

edit: lets try to adjust the margin.l attribute in fig.update_layout, also we will adjust the x value for the annotation to a negative value (e.g., -0.1)

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Canada'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Canada')

ticktext = ["Tick 1", "Tick 2", "Tick 3"]
desc = ["description 1", "description 2", "description 3"]
tickvals = np.arange(72, 78, 2)

fig.update_layout(
    yaxis=dict(title="", showgrid=True, showticklabels=False, tickvals=tickvals),
    margin=dict(l=100)  # Adjust the left margin
)

for i, (tick, d, val) in enumerate(zip(ticktext, desc, tickvals)):
    fig.add_annotation(
        dict(
            xref="paper",
            yref="y",
            x=-0.1,  # Set x to a negative value
            y=val,
            text=f"<b>{tick}</b>",
            showarrow=False,
            font=dict(size=15, color="green"),
            xanchor="left",
            yanchor="middle",
        )
    )
    fig.add_annotation(
        dict(
            xref="paper",
            yref="y",
            x=-0.1,  # Set x to a negative value
            y=val - 0.5,
            text=d,
            showarrow=False,
            font=dict(size=13, color="red"),
            xanchor="left",
            yanchor="middle",
        )
    )

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the annotation are in the plot and not on the left. And if I put `x=-0.2` the text disappear. Any idea to solve this ?

Comment: you welcome :)) I modified the answer